# Is there a way to tell latex to output a file containing a single chapter, while still using the formatting from the full document?

Tags: sectioning

I want to generate a pdf file containing just a single chapter from my dissertation. My first thought was to create a TeX file with just the text from the chapter.

```
\documentclass[msc, twoside, final]{Thesis}
\begin{document}
   %single chapter text goes here
\end{document}
```

The problem with this is that the document class my university gave me adds a lots of pages of boilerplate to the start of the file, which is very distracting. Section numbers also get wrong because it starts counting from 1.

I was thinking that maybe it would be better to just generate the pdf for the full dissertation and then use some tool to extract just the pages I need. Is there a way to do that while making sure that references and indexes still work?

Comment: You could just run `pdftk` on it. That's probably the simplest approach. But a LaTeX approach is probably also possible.

Comment: pdftk lets me select just the pages I want but it throws away the index and forces me to look up the page numbers by hand every time. I wonder if there might be an easier latex-only solution.

Comment: Are the chapters in their own separate files, or is the whole thing in one file?

Comment: They are in separate file. But the real problem is that just adding the document class adds 10+ pages of boilerplate to the output.

Comment: It sounds like your class could use an option to suppress the boilerplate. Perhaps you should write a question asking how to do that. :-) And then submit it to the class maintainers.

Comment: @hugomg If the content is in separate files anyways, loading the content with `\include{}` and then providing `\includeonly{}` in the preamble may be what you are looking for!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to answering the question.

First of all, to include only one of the chapters and not the others, the best way is to use the `\includeonly` command.

Put the separate chapters in separate files and include them in the main file with the `\include` command.

```
\begin{document}
\include{chapter01}  %chapter01.tex
\include{chapter02}  %chapter02.tex
%...
\end{document}
```

Then, in the document preamble, use the `\includeonly` to specify which include files should be rendered. The files that are not mentioned will count for section numbers but will not appear in the final document.

```
\documentclass{Thesis}

% This way, chapter 1 is skipped but chapter 2 still appears as "chapter 2"
\includeonly{chapter02}
```

Finally, for getting rid of the front-matter boilerplate, the best solution I could find was to edit the class file to add a custom option that skips the front matter. Id did this by imitating the way my class file defined the other options so I imagine that it could end up looking different for other people

```
% in Thesis.cls
% add an option to hide boilerplate
\newboolean{shouldShowFrontMatter}
\setboolean{shouldShowFrontMatter}{true}
\DeclareOption{NFM}{ \setboolean{shouldShowFrontMatter}{false} } 

% and put an if-then-else in the code that shows the front matter
\newcommand{\showfrontmatter}{%
   \ifthenelse{\boolean{shouldShowFrontMatter}}{
     % boilerplate goes here
    }{}
}
```

This now lets me skip the boilerplate by toggling a class option

```
\documentclass[NFM]{Thesis}
```